# Reload de Página Web

Tags: javascript, html

Eu pretendo ao clicar num botão ele me faça *reload* da página.

Aviso que o `<a>` esta num ficheiro de `navbar` é externo ao ficheiro original. Eu chamo a `navbar` através do **php** e esse botão esta na `navbar`.

Abaixo está o código que tentei implementar isso:

```js
function Refresh(){
  window.location.reload();
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <a onclick="Refresh"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-refresh"></i> <p>refresh</p></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esse meu método funciona em qualquer navegador, estando javascript habilitado ou não, enfim, 100% garantido. `<a href='URL_da_Propria_Pagina'><i class="fa fa-fw fa-refresh"></i> <p>refresh</p></a>`

Comment: Eu sei que sim, mas o que eu queria era uma função para ter na barra de navegação para que de reload em qualquer página visto que a minha barra de navegação é a mesma para todas as páginas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você esqueceu de chamar a função `Refresh()`:

```
<a onclick="Refresh()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-refresh"></i> <p>refresh</p></a>
```

Comment: É o que dá muitas horas ´frente de um computador em java é os ";" em javascript é os "()"

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e desculpe o tempo!!

Comment: SIm estou só aguardando os 5min